# How to determine which version of gfortran is installed?

Tags: upgrade, versions, fortran

I have the gfortran, but I have been told that gfortran versions 4.2 and older lacked some f90 functionality.  How do I determine which version is already installed?  Also, can I install the latest version even if I don't have superuser priviledges?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions. It would be much better if you divided your post into to separate questions - that makes them easier to answer, and this way you'll get most help.

Comment: Also, you posed 4 questions (including this) but you never accepted one of the several answers you got. This does not incentive people to spent their time to give you an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the version, try at the command line:

```
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
[...]
```

If you want to install without root privileges (no root password and no sudo rights), then you can install into your home directory only. You have to **download** the source code, then **compile** and **install** it **yourself**, then set up the appropriate environment.

Comment: Works for gfortran, but for ifort it just hangs... any idea how to do it for ifort?